# Expectation of positive random vector?

Tags: probability, expected-value

For $x$ positive random variable, I can calculate Its expectation by
$$E(x) = \int^\infty_0  1-F_x(t) \,dt$$

Now, suppose I have positive random vector (x,y), is there any equivalent result? What would happen if I calculate 
$$ \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 1-F_{x,y}(t1,t2)\,dt1\,dt2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $E(X,Y)$ is the **vector** $(EX,EY)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative then $E(X,Y) =((\int_0^{\infty} [1-F_X(t)] dt,(\int_0^{\infty} [1-F_Y(t)] dt)$.